# PHP extension unable to load dynamic library

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, lamp

I've installed LAMP. While I'm running my application it doesn't work and error log containing:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_bcmath.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Error occurs for each and every extension if I'm enable them.
I'm using PHP 7.0.

I tried enable extensions this ways but doesn't work.

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/ php_bcmath.so

; ... or with a path:

extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/ /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_bcmath.so
```

I'm getting just above statement in error log.
 When it saying cannot open shared object file: `No such file or directory.`Do I need change extension directory permission or what else there I can get rid of it?
I had tried other questions but doesn't work.

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.0

Comment: please install that module like this: `sudo apt install php7.0-bcmath`

Comment: Saying php7.0-bcmath is already the newest version (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4).

Comment: now why do you say it's not enabled?

Comment: Please comment out all those _modules_ you tried to enable manually

Comment: This isn't about only phph_bcmath. Error occur for all extensions. Also exist in extension directory . I already enabled them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54879/discussion-between-george-and-swapnil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are many modules installed on the system.  Php will use the ones that are actually enabled in the Apache2 configuration.  This way you choose which one will be used, not by installing and uninstalling them, but actually enabling the one you walk to be effective at the time.

You have to enable the installed modules for them to be used with Apache2.

Use this command:

```
$ sudo a2enmod [module-name]
```

After enabling a module, be sure to restart the Apache2 server:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Update:**

There is a conflict between difference version of the bcmath modules installed.  Perform these steps to address the issue.

```
$ sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
$ sudo cp 000-default.conf ospos.conf
$ sudo a2ensite ospos.conf
$ sudo nano ospos.conf
```

**Modify your new VirtualHost**

**Change from:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHos>
```

**Change to:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerName mysite.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ospos/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that the name **mysite.com** is to be the name of the URL you are typing in to bring up your site.  Add this **site name** to your `/etc/hosts` file with:

```
127.0.1.1       mysite.com
```

Now stop your apache2 server with:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

Run this to verify nothing is running on the port:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:80 | egrep LISTEN
```

Now start the server with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

You should not be able to access your site by the URL `sitename` you have added to your `ospos.conf` file.

Comment: Getting ERROR: Module php_sockets does not exist!

Comment: What is the exact command line, including the module name, you typed in that produced this error.

Comment: sudo a2enmod  php_bcmath or php-bcmath getting ERROR: Module php_sockets does not exist!

Comment: Give me a few minutes to duplicate erro on a test machine on the bench.

Comment: Ok. I'm thinking it because if modules aren't installed fully. Or versions. I had have same problem on win 7 but resolved after updating system. But here in lamp server I'm using default version of PHP-7.0. May if this is matter.

Comment: Can you give me a few lines of PHP Sample code to try to reproduce the error of your message.  I have install PHP/Msql Fresh on the computer on the work bench.  The modules are installed by default with `sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php`.  They appear to be enabled by default.  So if I could reproduce the error you are getting, it would help to troubleshoot why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54886/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-swapnil).

Comment: I'm getting errors because of I'm using OSPOS Open-Source Point of Sale and app need those extensions and that's why producing errors in log.  So I don't think I can give you code that'd produce same errors. Also I ain't familiar   with php. Thanks for helping.